# sscanf not extracting pattern

Tags: c, regex, scanf

I am trying to figure out the pattern I should be giving to sscanf.
I have a string abcde(1GB). I want to extract 1 and GB. I am using

```
    char list[]= "abcde(1GB)";
    int memory_size =0;
    char unit[3]={0} ;
sscanf(list, "%*s%d%s" , &memory_size, unit);
```

I do not see tokens extracted when I print I see memory_size =0 and NULL in unit.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your `sscanf()` string format should be:

```
sscanf(list, "%*[^(](%d%[^)]" , &memory_size, unit);
```

- `%[^)]` means catch charachters and stop ctaching when finding the charachter `)` or end of the string
- `%*[^(]` means:

  - `[^\(]` means  catch charachters and stop ctaching when finding the charachter `(` - as opposed to a more conventional `%s` - catching charachters and stop ctaching when finding space characters"
  - `*` means "read but not store"

Comment: @MOHAMED Thanks a lot !!! Can you please give me the explanation for this. Actually I am new to c. Sorry, If I am asking trivial question.

Comment: @Parthiv Shah Can you please give me the explanation for this. Actually I am new to c. Sorry, If I am asking trivial question.

Comment: @user2737926 please have a look at my answer.

Comment: @MOHAMED Minor: `"%s"` - first scanning and not saving white-space characters, then catching characters and stop catching when finding any white-space characters.

Answer (score 4):

The `%s` conversion specifier in the format string of `scanf` means that `scanf` will read a sequence of non-whitespace characters. The `*` in `%*s` is called the assignment suppression character. It means that `scanf` will read and discard the non-whitespace characters.

Since `%s` matches any sequence of non-whitespace characters, `%*s` in `"%*s%d%s"` means that `sscanf` will read an discard all the characters in the string `list`. **Therefore, there's nothing *left* in the array `list` to be read and assigned to the arguments `&memory_size` and `unit`.** This explains why `memory_size` and `unit` are unchanged. What you need is the format string

```
sscanf(list, "%*[^(](%d%2[^)]%*s", &memory_size, unit);
```

Here, in the format string `"%*[^(](%d%2[^)]%*s"` -

1. `%*[^(]` means that `sscanf` will first read and discard a sequence of character not containing the character `(`.
2. `(` means that `sscanf` will read and discard `(`.
3. `%d` means the `sscanf` will read a decimal integer.
4. `%2[^)]` means that `sscanf` will read at most a sequence of `2` characters not containing `)` and store them in the corresponding argument. This is to ensure that `sscanf` does not overrun the buffer `unit` in case the string to be stored is too large. It's one less than the size of `unit` to save space for the terminating null byte which is automatically added by `sscanf` at the end of the buffer.
5. `%*s` means `sscanf` will read and discard any sequence of leftover non-whitespace characters.

Answer (score 2):

plz go through the following link for the sscanf() function.

[sscanf function description](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm)

Now,

as per MOHAMED said  `%[^(]` is for catch the characters till `"("`

means `%*[^(]` truncate the string until `(` after that `%d` as integer data and then capture the string until `)`.

Answer (score 1):

After accept answer - supplemental

@MOHAMED answer is good, but below are candidate improvements.

1) Always check the `sscanf()` result to insure data was scanned as intended.

```
if (sscanf(list, "%*[^(](%d%[^)]", &memory_size, unit) != 2) ScanFailure();
```

2) When using the `"%s"` or `"%[]"` specifiers, include a limiting length. @ajay

```
char unit[3]={0} ;
//                          v--- 1 less than buffer size.
if (sscanf(list, "%*[^(](%d%2[^)]" , &memory_size, unit) != 2) ScanFailure();
```

3) Appending a `"%n"` (save scan position) is a sure-fire means of detecting the trailing `)` was there and extra junk was not at the end of the input string.
`"%n"` does not add to `sscaanf()` result.

```
int n = 0;
//                               )%n <--- Look for ) then save scan position
if (sscanf(list, "%*[^(](%d%2[^)])%n", &memory_size, unit, &n) != 2) || 
    list[n] != '\0') ScanFailure();
```

4) Making room for optional white-space may/may not be useful. Specifiers already allow optional leading white-space.  3 exceptions: `%c %[] %n`

```
   "%*[^(](%d%2[^)])%n"
//  v         v       v
   " %*[^(](%d %2[^)]) %n"
```